# Minimizing child modal form without minimizing main form and recover child modal form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a modal form which will do some long operation, during that operation user wants to minimize the modal form and do some other activity in Main form and the progress bar for modal form is shown in Main forms status bar

When user clicks on the status bar then modal form should appear to the user.

Summarize:

1. We have Main Winform and Child Modal Winform
2. The child modal form has some long operation which is shown by Progress Bar
3. If user minimizes the Child Form. It completely minimizes the Main From
4. But user want to minimize only the Child Form and do some operation in Main form

I tried two approaches

- Hiding the modal from on minimize event. The Child form is hidden
  then i am unable to recover the child form instance show it back from
  the main form since the object of modal form is disposed

  using (Form1 reportForm = new Form1(dbConnection))
  {
             reportForm.ShowDialog();
  }
- If i do the minimize of modal form it minimizes the main form also.
  In one stackoverflow it is mentioned that modal form is minimized then main form also will minimize Main form, this is right behaviour by design.

Please give me an approach for this issue.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make a lot of sense. Show some code, we're not coding monkeys

Comment: The answer is obvious. Don't make the second form modal

Comment: A dialog disables all of the other windows in the app.  So if you minimize it then there would be no other window that the user can interact with.  The OS does something about that usability problem, it minimizes the other windows as well.  You simply can't use ShowDialog() if you want to implement this requirement.  Be careful that you don't let the user start the same operation again.  The normal UI for this is a progress bar in the status strip, made visible only when the background operation is active.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a modal form is that the user **can't** do something else in the parent form.

Assuming your long running operation depends on input from the modal form you should do this:

1. Keep the form modal
2. Move the long operation into a backgroundworker
3. start the background worker upon closing of the modal form
4. open new non-modal form to show the progress from the background worker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do i need to keep the backgroundworker in Main Form?

Comment: @kalidoss Yes. the backgroundworker should be on the main form in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 protected void MDIChildNew_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){  
   Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();  
   // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.  
   newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;  
   // Display the new form.  
   newMDIChild.Show();  
}
```